# Simple pushdown automata question

Tags: formal-languages, automata, pushdown-automata

[image]

I'm trying to derive the language it represents. However, I'm kind of new to those topics. What happens if input b is gathered once or more than one time at state q without a in the stack? It does not have any transition, does it fail or since it is stuck is it accepted? example: abb

Comment: If all is well, your textbook defines PDAs, so you can look up what is supposed to happen. (Definitions may vary in different textbooks, so always look it up.)

Comment: checked it out, but couldn't find an answer to that. Presumably, it should fail

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all material that was originally written by others: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For many DFAs and PDAs, there is a computation path that will lead to a permanent reject state (and once computation reaches that reject state, any further transitions only return to that one state). For DFAs and PDAs that have such a state, these states (and all the transitions that lead to that state) are not shown in a diagram or are even left out of the transition description of such machines, with the understanding that there exists an ***implicit reject state***.

For machines with an implicit reject state, any computational step that is encountered that is not explicitly described in the machine's definition is understood to just lead to the implicit reject state, never to be able to return back to acceptance. It can be thought of as a "crash" state or a "dead" state.